# php filter_var() function

Tags: php, filter-var

Hi is there anyone to know why in this following php code, "if" statement return true:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <body>

    <?php
    // Variable to check
    $ip = "2001:0db8:85a3:08d3:1319:8a2e:0370:7334";

    // Validate ip as IPv6
    if (!filter_var($ip, FILTER_VALIDATE_IP, FILTER_FLAG_IPV6) === false) {
    echo("$ip is a valid IPv6 address");
    } else {
    echo("$ip is not a valid IPv6 address");
    }
    ?>

    </body>
    </html>
```

but in below code return false:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
     <html>
     <body>

     <?php
     // Variable to check
     $ip = "2001:0db8:85a3:08d3:1319:8a2e:0370:7334";

     // Validate ip as IPv6
     if (filter_var($ip, FILTER_VALIDATE_IP, FILTER_FLAG_IPV6) === true) {
     echo("$ip is a valid IPv6 address");
     } else {
     echo("$ip is not a valid IPv6 address");
     }
     ?>

    < /body>
    </html>
```

what I mean is, in first code the condition is (`false===false`)
but in second one the condition set to (`true===true`)
and as I said, first one return true and second return false. why?

Answer (score 3):

> [`filter_var`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.filter-var.php) returns the filtered data, or `false` if the filter fails.

In the first case, you're turning successful values into `false` using `!`, so you get exactly `false` and `false === false` is `true`. In the second case, you compare *"the filtered data"* to `true`, and `"2001:0db8:85a3:08d3:1319:8a2e:0370:7334" === true` is *not* `true`.

Just leave off the hyper-explicit `===` check:

```
if (filter_var($ip, FILTER_VALIDATE_IP, FILTER_FLAG_IPV6))
```

This succeeds if the `filter_var` check returns something *not falsey*, and fails when `filter_var` explicitly returns `false`.

Comment: @amir_sahanaqi That's all. If you use `===` operator to compare to `true`, the other side must be true, and not any other thing, even if it can be evaluated as `true`. For that, use `==` instead of `===`, or just no comparison, just evaluate as @deceze did in his solution.

Comment: but how about this code:
>```
<?php
$x=10;
$y=$x==10;
if ($y===true){
echo "yes"; 
}else{
echo "no";
};
```
which return `yes`.

Comment: Amir, in that code `$y` will be true or false but never a valid IP Address, so not the same thing at all. I think you are missing the most important part of the answer, the first line!! That `filter_var()` will return the IP address when it is valid and `false` ONLY if it is invalid